# IntelliJ - How to debug JSP that runs via an integrated Jetty server instance created in an application?

Tags: java, jsp, debugging, intellij-idea, jetty

I have searched for an answer to this, but everything I find is related to using standalone Jetty servers.  In this case, I'm trying to debug an open source java application and JSP file where the JSP runs in an instance of a jetty server created directly in the java application:

```
The java application creation of the Jetty server:
...
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
...
protected Server webserver;
...
webserver = new Server();
ServerConnector connector= new ServerConnector(webserver);
connector.setPort(port);  //8080
...
WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
webAppContext.setContextPath("/");
webAppContext.setResourceBase("src/webapps/qcksrv/");
...
```

So basically the application creates the Jetty server and runs it.

I can debug all the way up to the creation and execution of the Jetty server.
I can debug all of the application java code that is the underlying classes of the objects and methods used by the JSP. But I can not actually step through the JSP java code and debug it.

All of the solutions I have seen imply the use of a standalone Jetty server and settings related to that.

How do I setup and debug the JSP code in a situation like this?

Thanks!

Comment: what happens if you add a breakpoint on the JSP page?  do you start your app from within IntelliJ using the 'debug' option?

Comment: It won't let me.  I gives me a invalid notation with the message of "breakpoint does not belong to any class".  Yes, I start the app from within IntelliJ with the debug option.  It steps correctly through all the code but the JSP.  Breakpoints work fine with the exception of JSP.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA [doesn't support](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-166538) debugging web apps on the embedded app servers.

See also [this request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-164203) specific to debugging JSP on embedded Jetty server.

Comment: Thanks.  Does eclipse support it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Feel free to submit a separate question.